# How to determine the periodicity of this function?

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfy
$$f(x+y)f(x-y)＝(f(x))^2+(f(y))^2-1,\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}.$$
$\textbf{My question is: Is $f$ a periodic function}?$

In fact, let $y＝0$, then $(f(0))^2＝1$, and we can assume $f(0)＝1$. Then, if there exists $a\ne0$ such that $f(a)＝1$, then $f(x+a)＝f(x),\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. But how can find this $a$?

Comment: Does $f^2(x)$ here refer to the square $(f(x))^2$or a repeated composition $f(f(x))$? Your working seems to indicate the former. For future reference, please use explicit terminology. In general, $f^n(x)$ refers to repeated composition, except for trigonometric functions, where it is something of an abuse of notation based on historical usage.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should write $(f(x))^{2}$.

Comment: Fixed it for you. Although I'm not sure how you immediately went from $(f(0))^2 = 1$ to $f(0)=1$. Why did you not consider the possibility of a negative root?

Comment: If $f(0)＝-1$, then we can consider the function $-f$, and $-f$ also satisfy the identity.

Comment: $f(x)=\cos(2\pi x/a)$ satisfies the functional equation for any $a>0$.

Comment: Sure, but how to prove that $f$ must be or not to be a periodic function?

Comment: It need not be periodic. $f(x)=\cosh(kx)$ also satisfies the functional equation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's really a great example, but I don't know how you think of this example? It's difficult for me.

Comment: $\cosh(kx)=\cos(ikx)$.

Comment: The obvious generalization is $\cos(2\pi x/\alpha)$ for any complex $w\neq 0$. That said, such examples are _complex_-periodic (with period $\alpha$) even as they need not be real-periodic.